# git flow for feature branch

Tags: git, git-flow

The current git flow for the team.

3 branches in total

```
main
develop
feature
```

When we're in the development stage
When there is a new jira ticket, we will create a feature branch from develop.
After completing the feature, we will merge the feature into develop.
When we want to update the main branch, we will merge develop into main branch.

But the application is now open to public, we want to have better git flow.
As usual, if we finish the feature, we will merge it into develop branch.
Then the tester will test if the feature is completed without bug.
Once the testers've tested, they will ask us(developers) to deploy **ONLY** that feature, 
which is totally different from previous practice

For example, if developers complete feature A and then the testers've verified it in develop branch, after that we have to merge only feature A into main branch.

Therefore I want to know if there is any suggested flow for this situation.

Comment: The scope of delivery is usually matter of business priorities, not how the git is organized. Every release implies some commitment ready and if it's only one feature requested by business, why would you develop others? If business request other features, why QA wants just part of them?

Comment: @The Dreams Wind it means I have to push the feature A to main when feature A is tested, or push the feature B to main when it's completed etc

Comment: @The Dreams Wind they want us to deploy a new feature to main whenever a single feature completed

Comment: You may want to automate CI process in a way where every merge rolls out a build for QA, so they can choose from available builds for every feature. If QA team requests some specific order of features, it would mean one of three options: 1) micromanage development team progress, and artificially hold some features before the main one is ready. 2) merge features right into master, breaking synchronisation with develop and quality gates 3) implement feature toggle, that hides some parts of the finished work programmatically. Personally I don't think either of those options is practical

Comment: @The Dreams Wind but if I want to use the old way(merge develop into main branch), how can we make sure all features on develop branch are tested before merged into main branch.
For example, if we've completed feature A,B,C in develop branch, and QA only verified feature A and B, and we want to merge A and B into main

Comment: if they want you to deploy as soon as possible,then your dev. branch is obsolete and you just do QA for a feature branch and as soon as QA is done you merge it to master.Dev. branch implies a longer cycle of development of a product where you accumulate some set of features and then merge/ship them all together. You can have a release branch (short living branch, one per sprint (scrum terms)), and then ask your QA/business what they want in the next release and only develop things against that release branch. At the end of the sprint you merge that release to master and start new release.

Answer (score 2):

Git Flow works best when you periodically release a set of features whose state exists in a *single commit*. This is why Git Flow recommends creating a `release` branch from (a commit on) `develop` which you wish to test. This may be one feature or many, but the intention is that all of the features at that commit will be released. Bug fixes to any of those features are done on the `release` branch so that new development can simultaneously continue on `develop`.

Another way to think about Git Flow is this:

> Once you merge your code into `develop`, it is intended to be deployed with the next release (or the one after that if there is currently one in progress).

Even though the desired tweak you wish to make to your workflow is conceptually trivial, I believe it's enough that you should no longer use Git Flow. You might be able to stick with Git Flow if you made a new `release` branch for every feature, but then you would need to release them in the order they were created, or else you'll end up needing to do a lot of reverting to cut out specific features you wish to skip.

Based on the description of your situation, my proposed solution is to use what the maintainers of Git use, which is called [Gitworkflows](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows). The changes would include:

1. Rename your `develop` branch to `next`.
2. Periodically reset `next` to `main`. (Once per week, or iteration often works well.)
3. Have developers branch off of `main` for new features.
4. Merge those feature branches into `next` for integration testing.
5. Once approved, merge those feature branches into `main` and deploy to production.

That being said, at my company in one of our larger repos, we actually do a combination of both. We use Git Flow pretty much the "standard" way (and feature branches still come off of `develop`), but we validate the features by merging them into a branch called `next`, sometimes fixing them up and merging in again multiple times, before finally merging them into `develop`. By the time we create a `release` branch from `develop` it's already pretty well hardened, and bug fixes on the `release` branch are oftentimes minimal. This hybrid workflow may work well for you if you wish to sometimes release multiple features together. But if your normal use case is to release one feature at a time, then I'd probably consider skipping the overhead of Git Flow.